# Topics not visible on two machines

Tags: ros-melodic, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running ROS master on my PC and robot on embedded machine that connects to it. Recently, I have changed the embedded machine (before that, everything worked) and suddenly I cannot see remote topics on both machines (only local). My host PC runs Melodic and Embedded runs Kinetic but it should not matter as messages are the same.

From my host PC, I was able to SSH into my embedded machine and ping data. Also, I have added both machines in /etc/hosts, I have set the ROS_IP on both machines and I set the ROS_MASTER_URI on both machines with the host PC IP Address.

What could be wrong?

EDIT:

I also checked the netcat from this page:
http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup

I can confirm two machines can communicate

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/319866/topics-not-visible-on-two-machines/) by [EdwardNur](https://answers.ros.org/users/39496/edwardnur/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2019-03-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-03-29**:
What is the value of `ROS_HOSTAME` on both machine ?

**Comment by [EdwardNur](https://answers.ros.org/users/39496/edwardnur/) on 2019-03-29**:
@Delb I did not echo it as I have ROS_IP. I found an answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That is quite a unique issue I believe. I have configured DNS so that it redirects to a different DHCP and it worked.

---

Originally posted by [EdwardNur](https://answers.ros.org/users/39496/edwardnur/) with karma: 115 on 2019-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-29**:
If you have DNS with auto-updates to a DHCP server, it would be better to use `ROS_HOSTNAME`, as that would be automatically resolved to the correct IP.

If you use `ROS_IP` with such a setup, you run the risk of `ROS_IP` containing an old IP, resulting in the problem you reported in your OP.